# Database for Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and searched for this topic on the internet but still not sure which would be the best choice. I am writing an app that shows users details about a movie. I want to add to this application a database that stores for each user their favorite movies, and movies they want to watch in the future. What would be a good choice for adding a database? Would a client-server architecture fit this app? (writing it in Java)

Comment: If your requirement is only for users to store their own preferential data on the phone, then look into using embedded SQLite.  If on the other hand you want _all_ user data in a common place, then you'll need some kind of web application running in the cloud with a SQL database behind it.  As to _which_ SQL database you choose...it might not even matter for your app.

Comment: I want the user to have an activity in which all his favorite movies that he selected will appear. I don't exactly need the data to be in a common place. Also would a client-server architecture be needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to implement a local database, I would strongly suggest using [Room persistence library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). However, if the data you wish to save is fairly simple (let's say it is an object with 2-3 properties), you could consider saving them to [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) as json strings.